# Understanding Clojure partial

Tags: clojure

I'm reading the Clojure Programming book. I'm at an example about partials and it go like this:

```
(def only-strings (partial filter string?))
```

The thing is, if the i write the next function:

```
(defn only-strings [x] (filter string? x))
```

I can have the same result:

```
user=> (only-strings [6 3 "hola" 45 54])
("hola")
```

What are the benefits of using a partial here? Or the example is just to simple to show them? Could somebody please give me an example where a partial would be useful. Many thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The benefits of `partial` in this case is that you can fix the first argument and bind it to `string?`.

That's even all `partial` does. Predefining the first parameters as you can see in yours and in Arthur's example.

```
(def foo (partial + 1 2))

(foo 3 4)    ;; same as (+ 1 2 3 4)
;; > 10
```

With partial I bound the first two arguments to `1` and `2` in this case.

#### Why could this be useful?

You may want to use `map` or `apply` on a function, which takes two arguments. This would be very bad, because map and apply take a function, which one needs one argument. So you might fix the first argument and use `partial` for this and you get a new function which only needs one argument. So it can be used with map or apply.

In one of my projects I had this case. I thought about using `partial` or an anonymous function. As I only needed it in one case, I used a lambda. But if you need it more than one time, than defining a new function with partial would be very useful. Also it is more readable.

Answer (score 11):

This eventually comes down to a matter of personal style, anything you do with partial you can do with an anonymous function, though sometimes `partial` makes it prettier. applying the first couple arguments to a variadic function is one example:

```
user> (def bigger+ (partial + 7 42)) 
#'user/bigger+
user> (bigger+ 1 2)
52
```

compared to:

```
user> (def bigger+ (fn [& nums] (apply + 7 42 nums)))
#'user/bigger+
user> (bigger+ 1 2)
52
```

Though of course you are free to prefer the second one if it looks better to you.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example:
(see the difference between DEFN and DEF)

```
(defn addDomain [domain user] ( str user domain))   
(def buildEmail (partial addDomain "@domain.com"))
(buildEmail "info")  

;; "info@domain.com"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want an example of how partial functions are useful, there's a real-world example that's very common in the Java world, where Java and Spring recreate partial function application (albeit in a clunky way).

Say you have a singleton component FooService that you configure in Spring, it's configured with the scope of singleton and has some stuff injected into it like a BarDao. The FooService has a bunch of business methods like retrieveBarsForSomeReason().

When the application starts up it reads the application context which instantiates the FooService and injects the BarDao into it as an instance variable. Later on the application calls methods on the FooService and the methods call on the BarDao as part of their work.

So this isn't a real object and there's nothing OO going on here, the methods on the service object are basically functions. Injecting state, in this example the BarDao, is equivalent to binding the object using partial so that you don't have to include it on later calls.